# A query to get me specific alphabetic order for sybase

Tags: sybase

I have a table called telephone_contacts that contain two columns:

> telephone_contacts (
>     Name    varchar(100)
>     Numbers number(20)
>   )

the column name contains about 20,000 rows.

I want to filter the name by alphabetic , example:

I want a query that get me only the first 6 alphabetic (A , B, C , D ,E ,F G)

Then, a query that get me the last 6 alphabetic (U,V,W,X,Y,Z)

example: the column name contains the following data:
Abe, car, night, range, chicken, zoo, whatsapp,facebook, viber Adu , aramt, Bike, Male, dog,egg 
I want a query that get me only (A , B, C , D ,E ,F G) so the results will be 
abe ,care ,chicken facebook,adu,aramt,bike, dog, egg 
the rest are ignored

In oracle I can do it like this, how do I do it for sybase?

> SELECT * FROM user_tab_cols WHERE SUBSTR(UPPER(table_name),1) BETWEEN 'A' and 'Q'
>   SELECT * FROM user_tab_cols WHERE SUBSTR(UPPER(table_name),1) BETWEEN 'P' and 'Z'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sybase you can use the regex (regular expression) to sepecify character ranges [A-G]  Assuming your server is set to case insensitive you can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM telephone_contacts WHERE name LIKE "[A-G]%"
SELECT * FROM telephone_contacts WHERE name LIKE "[U-Z]%"
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM telephone_contacts WHERE name BETWEEN "A%" and "G%"
SELECT * FROM telephone_contacts WHERE name BETWEEN "U%" and "Z%"
```

If you find that your server is case sensitive, then you can do what was suggested in another answer, and use `upper(name)`

Answer (score 1):

It's even simpler:

```
select * from yourtable where upper(name) like "[A-Q]%"

select * from yourtable where upper(name) like "[P-Z]%"
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  HTML markups are not used here.  For formatting you can use the options at the top of the text window.

Comment: @MichaelGardner Do you have any idea of how to solve my problem?